# Existe algo que dê o caminho do CSS?

Tags: html, css, classes, div

Preciso de algo que faça com que eu consiga referenciar o caminho do `CSS` mais rapidamente, tipo um recurso no inspecionar do Google, pois é complicado ficar descobrindo as sequências de centenas de `divs` dentro de `divs`.

Tipo algo que me dê o caminho pronto exemplo:

```
#look .love .system .armazen form .castel input {  display: block;}
```

Deixar o caminho pronto para só copiar e colar para acessar.

Comment: Como assim? não entendi

Comment: Botão direito em cima do elemento > **Inspecionar Elemento**.

Comment: Tente editar sua pergunta e explique melhor o que você precisa.

Comment: Você tem um bom motivo para querer usar esses "caminhos completos"? Em geral, quanto mais simples o seletor css, melhor.

Comment: A pergunta está clara sim, o que ele quer, é saber se há uma maneira de copia toda a hierarquia de algum elemento de uma forma rápida, e há sim, existem extensões para o google chrome que faz isto. ou você pode também abrir seu inspecionar elemento, clicar com o botão direito no elemento desejado e seguir > Copy > Copy selector. Como o bfavarretto citou, não é muito performático, se possível não utilize todo o caminho, apenas o necessário. Caso possível, reabram a pergunta que eu posto a resposta explicando tudo certinho para ele. Obrigado.